# Un-matching vote count on close popup

Tags: support, review-queues

During [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15571563), the close reasons given were not matching the votes of the popup.

Close reasons:

- too broad
- off-topic
- unclear what you're asking

Popup votes:

- 1 for off-topic
- 2 for too broad

Note: I voted "unclear" subsequently.

[image]

[Edit]

It's doing its mismatch with a different pattern [on this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15571694):

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a bug. The review page explicitly says "flagged" so the reasons you are shown include flags which don't count as close votes

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned by @psubsee2003 this not a bug but by design.

When a user with less then 3000 reputation flags a post for closing, the reason they choose is mentioned on the review page. Once users with close vote privileges start casting their votes, the close dialog will show the counts on the close reasons your peers have chosen.

How many flags were raised for a specific reason is hidden for the close voters.